# Python Pandas Split DF

Tags: python, pandas

pls review the code below, is there a more efficient way of splitting one DF into two? In the code below, the query is run twice. Would it be faster to just run the query once, and basically say if true send to DF1, else to DF2 ; or maybe after DF1 is created, someway to say that DF2 = DF minus DF1

**code:**

```
x1='john'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None, engine='python', quoting=3)
df = df[0].str.strip(' \t"').str.split('[,|;: \t]+', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: 'data'}) 
df1= df[df.email.str.startswith(x1)]
df2= df[~df.email.str.startswith(x1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to compute the mask `df.emailclean.str.startswith(x1)` twice.

```
mask = df.emailclean.str.startswith(x1)
df1 = df[mask].copy() # in order not have SettingWithCopyWarning 
df2 = df[~mask].copy() # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas
```

Comment: kindly add copy at the end :-)

Comment: @YOBEN_S Good suggestion, but do we know if OP needs a copy?

Comment: In this df1 , when setting a new column , it will have copy warning ~ , this is just my coding behavior ~

Comment: @YOBEN_S I'm not entirely sure what you mean but feel free to edit your suggestion into my answer.

Comment: Thanks both. how do I delete 'mask' from the memory after df1,df2 are split? I am trying to be as efficient as possible (big data)

Comment: @rogerwhite With `del mask` the object will be garbage collected eventually if `mask` was the only reference.